# I know how to run js methods when the page finish loading, how can I force certain js to load after everything else?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-typeahead

My project currently uses two different versions of jquery; 1.2.6 and 1.9.0. I use 1.9 only for bootstrap typeahead. It seems in IE8-9, the version somehow reverts back to 1.2.6 even though I used noConflict() when I invoke the typeahead; strangely this only happens on some pages randomly with maybe 10-20% chance of happening.

The typeahead doesnt have to load first/second or whatever, it can load last. Is there a way to force the call to typeahead LAST; ie after pages finish loading and every other js has loaded?

Comment: This is a poor practice. Simply use only jQuery 1.9 and jQuery migrate.

Comment: thats what im thinking as well, but the app is big and time is little..

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried $(window).load() instead of $(document).ready().
Another option is update your code that need jquery version of 1.2.6.

Comment: yep upgrading jquery version would be in the future.. i will try out this window.load().

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant or maintainable solution but simply put the jQuery code at the end of your page. The order in which you call $(document).ready() is the order it is executed, so:

```
<head>
  <script ...>
    $(function(){ ... called first ... });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  ...
  <script ...>
    $(function(){ ... called last ... });
  </script>
</body>
```

**As mentioned rather migrate to 1 version of jQuery!**

Answer (score 0):

We've had similar issue and what I've done is created new master page for new version of jquery.

After a while when there was more time we've upgraded whole project to newest version.